# Making QR codes with circular dots and markers in Python

Tags: python-3.x, qr-code

I am trying to make a QR code using Python qrcode library similar to that embedded above. I am able to print circular dots but I am not able to print circular markers and define the distance between the dots. If someone is able to make similar QR codes also using a different library it is OK for me.

```
import qrcode
from qrcode.image.styledpil import StyledPilImage
from qrcode.image.styles.moduledrawers.pil import CircleModuleDrawer

qr = qrcode.QRCode(error_correction=qrcode.constants.ERROR_CORRECT_L)
qr.add_data('Some data')
img_0 = qr.make_image(image_factory=StyledPilImage, module_drawer=CircleModuleDrawer())
img_0.save("img0.png")
```

[image]

Comment: add your existing code